# Twitch Bot unable to send messages to other channels (Exception of 1 account being able to)

Tags: java, bots, irc, twitch

So I’m trying to make a bot for twitch, through irc (pIRC on java) and I’m having issues.

I only seem to be able to send messages to the user's own channel. Except for one account, which can send messages to any channel for some reason.

Every account that I connect to twitch to gives me these verbose messages:

```
1625704200190 :tmi.twitch.tv 375 NAME :-
1625704200191 :tmi.twitch.tv 372 NAME :You are in a maze of twisty passages, all alike.
1625704200191 :tmi.twitch.tv 376 NAME :>
```

and if I choose to join the channel (not necessary to send a message) it says:

```
625704227005 >>>JOIN #CHANNEL
1625704227227 :NAME!NAME@NAME.tmi.twitch.tv JOIN #CHANNEL
1625704227461 :NAME.tmi.twitch.tv 353 NAME = #CHANNEL :NAME
1625704227461 :NAME.tmi.twitch.tv 366 NAME #CHANNEL:End of /NAMES list
```

and sending a single message looks like:

```
1625704638354 >>>PRIVMSG #CHANNEL :hi
```

It looks like this when the message goes through AND when it doesn’t go through. No difference in the logs. No exceptions thrown or errors in the logs.

When I started the bot earlier I was trying out different stuff and different accounts and they all worked but then this issue suddenly happened and only one account can send messages to every channel (my normal twitch acc, not the bot). So dno what’s going on.

Anyone knows what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell whats the problem if you even have a error.

sending a message should look like this:

```
< PRIVMSG #<channel> :This is a sample message
> :<user>!<user>@<user>.tmi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #<channel> :This is a sample message
```

If this doesnt help you can try to reconnect with ssl:
here is the guide https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc/guide